# How to flatten List of Lists in Kotlin?

Tags: android, list, kotlin, android-recyclerview, flatmap

I have a list of objects of class AA that contain a date and a list of objects of class BB:

```
data class AA(
    val date: LocalDate,
    val bb: List<BB>
)

@Parcelize
data class BB(
    val x: Int,
    val y: String,
    val z: String
) : Parcelable
```

I want to create a single List (flatten `List<AA>`) that will look like this:

```
 listOf(
    date obj
    BB obj
    BB obj
    date obj
    BB obj
    date obj
    BB obj
    BB obj 
    BB obj)
```

Instead of:

```
 listOf(
    date obj, listOf(BB obj, BB obj)
    date obj, listOf(BB obj)
    date obj, listOf(BB obj, BB obj, BB obj))
```

I tried using flatMap, but I only manage to flatten one part - BB.
How to crate a list with date and BB items?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Divide elements on groups in RecyclerView or Grouping Recyclerview items ,say by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41447044/divide-elements-on-groups-in-recyclerview-or-grouping-recyclerview-items-say-by)

Comment: @Hardik Chauhan - My question was how to flatten the list. The RecyclerView is what it will be used for and is not relevant (I removed it). Anyway the answer there is about grouping. I need to represent existing objects. So it's not a duplicate question!

Comment: what is `item` in the flattened list? It does not seem to appear in the `List<AA>`

Comment: @leonardkraemer - Basically if my List<AA> looks like that: listOf((date1,listOf(2,a,b), (date2,listOf((3,v,d),(5,c,j))) etc. Then I want a list: listOf(date1,(2,a,b),date2,(3,v,d),(5,c,j))

Comment: I edited to make it more clear

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As answered by [@DYS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58027389/4265739) you can and should use [`flatten`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flatten.html) to flatten a list. My answer covers how to achieve the special case stated in the question.

You can do it this way:

```
val a = listOf(
    AA(LocalDate.now(), listOf(BB(1, "1", "1")))
)
val flattened = a.flatMap { aa -> mutableListOf<Any>(aa.date).also { it.addAll(aa.bb) }}
```

see [complete example](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/u1b8lg2833b3mcmihhhoq2n172/fv6734jjkfpgngiagrf4ev6qgv)

Basically you use `flatMap`, create a `MutableList<Any>` with the `date` and then `addAll` items of `BB` in the `also` block. Probably there is a more elegant way to do it but this one came to me first.

Simply using `flatten` does not work here, because AA does not implement `iterable`.

Answer (score 46):

The simplest one I know of is the extension `flatten()` function to `Iterable`. Since `List` is a subclass of the latter, it is applicable.

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flatten.html

```
val deepList = listOf(listOf(1), listOf(2, 3), listOf(4, 5, 6))
println(deepList.flatten()) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: You can also do this: `listOf(1) + listOf(2,3) + listOf(4,5,6)` (which is shorthand for: `listOf(1).plus(listOf(2,3)).plus(listOf(4,5,6))`) to get the same results.

Comment: As you can see OP has different types for nested lists. How is this even related to the question and why people keep upvoting this?

Comment: @Farid I think the emphasis of this question is more about flattening list of lists than about list of lists of different types, as suggested by the title of the question.

Comment: @DYS Well if you answer questions by only title, then nothing to say. Content of the question is there for a reason right?! Imagine how ambiguous answers you would get if people only read the title and answered accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this:

```
fun flattenNestedList(list: List<List<Any>>?) = list?.flatten() ?: emptyList()
```

Comment: As you can see OP has different types for nested lists

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to flatten lists:

```
val flatList = listOf<String>("A", "B", *listOf("C", "D").toTypedArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

Some year after but here some simple examples:

**With lists of lists**

```kotlin
val array = listOf(listOf("a", "b"), listOf("c", "b"))
.flatten().toTypedArray()
```

**With arrays of arrays**

```kotlin
val array = arrayOf(arrayOf("a", "b"), arrayOf("c", "b"))
.flatten().toTypedArray()
```

**With lists of arrays**

```kotlin
val array = listOf(arrayOf("a", "b"), arrayOf("c", "b"))
.flatMap { it.toList() }.toTypedArray()
```

hope to help someone.