# Can i get all names to 1 recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Can i get all names from my database to 1 recyclerview?  It's complicated because i need to load month after day and after else name to 1 recyclerview. Here is my database

For example, in recyclerview, i need:

```
<br />

Oktober <br /> 
10 lucia <br />
10 petra <br />
18 adam <br /> <br />
November <br /> 
15 sona <br /> <br />
```

[image: database image].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Divide elements on groups in RecyclerView or Grouping Recyclerview items ,say by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41447044/divide-elements-on-groups-in-recyclerview-or-grouping-recyclerview-items-say-by)

Comment: Have you solved the problem? Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: He doesnt has there any code of his layouts for example layout from mainactivity